# Use the same commit abbreviation length for git blame as other commands

Tags: git, git-blame

The `git blame` command shows commit hashes abbreviated to a length that is one character longer than other commands. For example:

```
$ git log --oneline       
9fb6f706 (HEAD -> master) second commit
0af747a8 first commit
$ git blame foo   
9fb6f7064 (gilles 2020-11-15 12:28:09 +0100 1) revised
^0af747a8 (gilles 2020-11-15 12:27:41 +0100 2) world
```

I frequently copy-paste an abbreviated hash from the `blame` output and search for it in logs or in the set of commits in an interactive rebase. But because the abbreviation is one character longer in the `git blame` output, I have to remember to delete the last character, otherwise the search can't find anything.

For scripting I'd use unabbreviated hashes and porcelain formats. But for interactive use, I want to use abbreviated hashes.

Setting the `core.abbrev` option doesn't help: `git blame` adds one to that. Setting `core.abbrev` and calling `blame --abbrev` with a value that's one less works, but is not a good solution because I lose the benefit of git's heuristics to determine a good length for short commit ids, and I have to pass this option explicitly or use a different command name as an alias.

How can I make a plain `git blame` use the same length for abbreviated commit ids as other git commands?

Comment: That's interesting … Maybe a bug? I can confirm this behavior with latest Git built from source. Can you take this to the Git mailing list?

Comment: @knittl It's by design: [“one more abbrev length is needed for the boundary commit”](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.29.2/builtin/blame.c#L660). But that's only for a corner case which is mostly useless (the boundary commit is identifiable by other means anyway) and it's annoying, so I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: Given the source code, it looks like you can't really get around it (well, I suppose you could use an alias to invoke `git blame` with an explicitly shortened abbreviation count). You might try getting in the habit of just always deleting the last character from all searches. :-)

Comment: very annoying, looking for the hash commit of blame and after waste many time realize that blame hash have one more character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom Git command for this. Save the code below in an executable file called `git-blame-1` somewhere on your `$PATH`. Now you can run `git blame-1` instead of `git blame`, and the commited ID abbreviations will have the same length as with other commands such as `git rebase`.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o pipefail

# The blame command adds one hex digit to abbreviated commit IDs to ensure that
# boundary commits are unambiguous (boundary commits have leading ^ and then
# just enough hex digits to be unambiguous, while other commits have an
# extra hex digit so that they're the same length as boundary commits).
# This alias removes the extra digit, so the abbreviated IDs are the same
# length as other commands such as log and rebase -i. With low probability,
# this can make the abbreviation of boundary commit IDs ambiguous.

# Implementation note: we use a sed filter to detect lines starting with an
# optional escape sequence for coloring, then an optional ^, then hex digits
# and a space. The sed filter here removes the last hex digit.

# Note that $sed_filter does not contain any single quote, so it can be
# included in a shell snippet as "...'$sed_filter'...".
sed_filter='s/^\(\(0-9;]*m\)*\^*[0-9a-f]*\)[0-9a-f] /\1 /'

if [ -t 1 ]; then
  GIT_PAGER="sed '$sed_filter' | ${GIT_PAGER:-${PAGER:-less}}" git blame "$@"
else
  git blame "$@" | sed "$sed_filter"
fi
```

The script takes care of preserving paging when running on a terminal. This has to be a separate script, not an alias, because shell aliases run from the root directory, so they don't work correctly from a subdirectory.

I also define an alias to save typing. In my `.gitconfig`:

```
b1 = blame-1     # blame with standard abbreviated commit IDs
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for digging through the source code. I'm afraid your only solution – rather workaround is to define a custom alias.

```
git config --global alias.blame2 '!git -c core.abbrev=6 blame'
```

Comment: Even though I still don't know why blame (or "boundary commits" in blame) would require a different abbreviation length. As long as the abbrev has enough digits, it is already unique. I'd still suggest taking this to the Git mailing list

Comment: It's explained in the [commit message that inroduced the `+ 1`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b31272f704d03258a90b0e83e0f5c8df5c038ae6): the boundary commit is shown as `^1234567` instead of `12345678`, and git calculates the length in order to ensure that `12345678` is guaranteed to be unique, but `1234567` isn't guaranteed to be unique. I'm not convinced that this corner case is worth the trouble, but I have to live with it.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': yes, but the uniqueness is not affected by the commit being a boundary commit or not. Either 7 characters are sufficient to guarantee uniqueness, or 8 are. That applies regardless of the "boundariness" of the commit. If 7 characters do not uniquely identify a single commit – i.e. the hash prefix is ambiguous – then even for `git log`, more than 7 characters have to be displayed.